# Is getting a reference letter from both advisors a good idea?

Tags: application, postdocs, recommendation-letter

I am applying for a postdoc which is asking for 2 referees. I have a main and co-supervisor who would both write a good letter and know me well. Is it best that I put them both down or is it best practice to only put the main supervisor down and find the second referee from another source, even if they don't know me as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a judgement call as we can't see the letters nor guess what the hiring committee will prefer. But, if they are the two people who can best predict your success in the position, then they are probably the best letter writers.

But see if you can get them to focus on different things, so that it doesn't seem like just one letter. Maybe a three person sit-down would help for you to suggest it. You could, perhaps, just let them work out the details. But that would depend on your relationship with them so it might be possible or not. Good luck..